# Game over return

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am during writing game. When condition (playerlife < 1) is meet, game should stop. Whole game is in singlePlayer function. The problem is, I don't know how to end this function. Simple placing condition inside singlePlayer function doesn't work because it is checked only once during starting a game.

```
if (playerlife < 1) {
 return;
}
```

I also tried to put this condition in interval and check if condition is meet continously but I doesn't work and anyway it doesn't looks like a good idea.

Below is part of code where after moving player there are checked some conditions. Game is similar to old school "Frogger". When player jump in to the water then he lost 1 life. After loosing 3 lives game should be over.

```
$(function() {
function singlePlayer() {

  checkPosition(x, y) {
    for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
      if (x == raftsTab[i].PosX && y == raftsTab[i].PosY) {
        let thisRaft = raftsTab[i];
        console.log(x, y);
        console.log(thisRaft);
        clearInterval(MoveToPlayer);
        movePlayer(thisRaft);
        return;
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
      if (x !== raftsTab[i].PosX && y !== raftsTab[i].PosY && y !== 0 && y !== 5 && y !== 10) {
        player1.lifes = player1.lifes - 1;
        //player dead after loosing 3 lives - it would be perfect if game could be ended from here
        $('.lifes').text("Player lifes: " + player1.lifes);

        for (var i = 0; i < trophiesTab.length; i++) {
          if (player1.trophie - 1 == i) {
            trophiesTab[i].show();
            player1.trophie = -1;
          }
        }
        player1.PosX = 5;
        player1.PosY = 10;
        clearInterval(MoveToPlayer);
        changePosition();
        return;
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < trophiesTab.length; i++) {
      if (x == trophiesTab[i].PosX && y == trophiesTab[i].PosY && player1.trophie == -1) {
        trophiesTab[i].hide();
      }
    }

    if (x == 5 && y == 0 && player1.trophie !== -1) {
      tresure1 = tresure1 + player1.trophie;
      player1.items = player1.items + 1;
      $('.items').text("Gathered items: " + player1.items + "/3");
      player1.trophie = -1;
      console.log(tresure1);
    }
    clearInterval(MoveToPlayer);
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post at least a little more of the code?

Generally speaking, games are written as a loop, where you accept inputs, process whatever the game rules are, check for an end-of-game condition, and then repeat.

It seems like you should be checking the number of player lives near the end of the loop.

Comment: then presumably you need to put this check elsewhere in the function... perhaps when `playerlife` changes?

Comment: You should look in your code for places where the value of `playerlife`  changes and decide in those places whether to continue.

Comment: I added part of code where I got problem. I hope it would be helpfull

Comment: Anyone have some idea?